# Different behaviour after blur between HTML input and HTML textarea with respect to spellcheck, why?

Tags: html

We're observing different behaviours between input and textarea fields in our application with respect to the spellcheck attribute.
When they have the focus we observe identical behaviour (or we haven't seen any difference); they both underline the spelling errors.

But when they lose focus, they look different. The textarea continues to highlight the spelling errors but the input no longer highlight them.
Observed on different versions of different browsers.
We prefer the textarea behaviour.

Why is there a difference? And is there an attribute, or CSS, that can be set on the input field to keep highlighting the errors after losing focus?

Comment: This is browser-specific.   MacOS Safari and Firefox show underlines on both input and textarea whether in or out of focus; MacOS Chrome follows the behavior you describe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Why is there a difference?

Cause browser settings might be setup differently in every browser. If a user doesn't likes auto spell checking he can disable it in browser settings. You can not re-enable it with javascript or CSS.

> And is there an attribute, or CSS, that can be set on the input field
>   to keep highlighting the errors after loosing focus?

No, there is no such attribute.